# php, imap, gmail and the dreaded Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}'

Tags: php, ssl, gmail, imap

on my localhost, no problem, php script works.
on my host server the dreaded "Can't connect to '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}' "

the code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' 
. imap_last_error());
```

Their php config appears to have all the necessary:
PHP Version 5.2.17

'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php5' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-cli' '--disable-cgi' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/lib' '--disable-all' '--enable-libxml' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ctype' **'--with-curl=/usr' '--with-curlwrappers'** '--enable-dom' '--enable-exif' '--enable-filter' '--with-pcre-dir=/usr' '--enable-ftp' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-gd=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-ttf=/usr' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-t1lib=/usr' '--with-gettext=/usr' '--with-gmp=/usr' '--enable-hash' '--with-iconv' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mcrypt=/usr' '--with-mhash=/usr' '--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/magic.mime' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-sqlite' '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-pdo-mysql=/usr' '--enable-posix' '--enable-reflection' '--enable-session' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-spl' '--enable-soap' '--enable-json' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-tokenizer' '--with-regex=system' '--enable-xml' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--enable-xmlreader' '--with-xmlrpc' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--enable-zip' **'--with-imap=/usr/lib64/dovecot/imap' '--with-imap-ssl'** '--with-pear=/usr/local/lib/php' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs'

curl

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

imap

IMAP c-Client Version   2004
SSL Support     enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled

openssl

OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

---

So can someone gimme a hint as to what is missing that it should throw a can't connect to error?
It does not even do  imap_open.
    Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream blahblah
Help?

Comment: I do not have a telnet client so do not know. Their faq does not state that port 993 is blocked. Can I use an alternate? eg. 25?

Comment: I'd try 465 or 587 next.

Comment: what host are you using?  Do they allow these types of connections?

Comment: @pivot: s'a freebie host I can't complain. Dunno if they 'allow', they got ssl and imap and curl support setup. How much more invitation does a boy need? Why would they config to allow, and then withhold, that'd just be mean.  Gonna try for 465 & 587

Comment: @j08691. same story with port 465 nd 587. Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,587: Connection timed out"

Comment: @John I had a similar situation a few months ago was able to connect to gmail and everything, then host switched servers and shut down all connections, banged my head for two days then contacted them and found out what had happened.

Comment: @pivot: ok, but then why would they not change config to disallow ssl and curl and imap. Do you see where I am coming from? If its setup means its a ok to use. Can't see why they would leave imap implemented if it was causing so many problems. Or their faq would state: Please do NOT Implement IMAP. IT IS VERBOTEN on a free host.

Comment: @John Yea I hear you, let us know if you find a solution I would be interested to know what was going on.

Comment: @John: Because those people who are setting up the port configuration often have very little to do with people who are setting up the software.  Likely, it's a fairly stock install.